# How to sync e-mail outlook2010 and sharepoint2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, outlook, outlook-2010

I need to sync emails between outlook2010 and sharepoint 2010. I have been searching, but found syncing contacts, calendars and tasks. Links and examples will be appreciated.

Question: What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Sharepoint webpart [`OWAInboxPart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.portal.webcontrols.owainboxpart.aspx) which will display email from Exchange without having to store the emails within Sharepoint.

Comment: how to make this webpart authenticate current user automatically , not ask user every time to enter password

Comment: @MahmoudFarahat - You should post this comment as a new question and link to this question. You need to follow the Q & A format as SO isn't a discussion forum. You will have better luck getting answers.

Answer (score 1):

The question is Why? Outlook is a communication tool not a storage facility. There is an outlook web parts in SharePoint that allow you to display email in sharepoint if this is your goal.

Comment: Could you provide me with links to this web part.